# Questions about DLL load order

Tags: dll, loader

As we know, for implicitly linked DLLs of an executable, at load
time, they will be loaded into memory by the loader, and the
loader will calls their entry point to initialize them as well.
This is a linear process - they are loaded one by one, and be
initialized one by one. So the most important thing is the order,
the order affects a lot of things.

**Q1**: The initialize order can be different from the load order, is
this true ?

**Q2**: The load order is affected by the import table, is this true ?

**Q3**: The initialize order of independent DLLs is affected by the
import table - A DLL may be initialized first because it appears
first, is this true ?

Answer (score 0):

"The process is created in a suspended state with the
CREATE_SUSPENDED flag to CreateProcess. Detours then modifies the
image of the application binary in the new process to include the
specified DLL as its first import. Execution in the process is
then resumed. When execution resumes, the Windows process loader
will first load the target DLL and then any other DLLs in the
application's import table, before calling the application entry
point."

I found this important message on the document of Microsoft
Detours. So for Q2 and Q3, yes, it's true. I will do more research
on this topic.